# What is the condition for $ax+b$ and $a'x+b'$ to belong to same equivalence class under modulo $(x^2+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is how our lecture on equivalence classes (abstract algebra) went:

> Let's consider an example, first. For $4$ modulo, the equivalence
>   classes are $\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}$. To find which equivalence
>   class $7$ belongs to, write it as $4k+r$ (where $ 0\leq r\leq 3$).The
>   $r$'s form an equivalence class. We can extend this concept to
>   polynomials. Suppose we have to find the equivalence class to which
>   $2x^2+4x+5$ under modulo $x^2+1$, we write it in the form
>   $2(x^2+1)+(4x+3)$. That's is when divided by $(x^2+1)$, we get an
>   equivalence class of remainders of the form $ax+b$. $ax+b$ and $a'x+b$
>   belong to the same class if $(a-a')$ and $(b-b')$ are divisible by
>   $(x^2+1)$.

I lost it at the last line. What does the professor mean by if $(a-a')$ and $(b-b')$ are divisible by $(x^2+1)$ (how does division of numbers by polynomial make sense)? Or did I mishear/misinterpret something? Anyhow, I'd like to know the actual condition for $ax+b$ and $a'x+b'$ to be considered to belong to the equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b,a',b'$ are numbers, then it is correct. In fact numbers are divisible by $x^2+1$ iff they are zero.

What your teacher is trying to tell you is that $ax+b$ represent all equivalence classes, since every polynomial can be reduced to one of them, and they all belong to different classes of equivalence.

Comment: What if they're not numbers? How do we go about it then?

Comment: @Blue If they are polynomial, then it's still true that  $ax+b$ and $a′x+b'$ belong to the same class if $(a−a′)$ and $(b−b′)$ are divisible by $(x^2+1)$ (it's fairly easy to see). The problem is that the converse is not true: suppose $a=x$, $b=1$, $a'=b'=0$. Then $(a−a′)$ and $(b−b′)$ are not divisible by $(x^2+1)$, but $ax+b=x^2+1$ and $a'x+b'=0$ so they belong to the same class